# unable to open image, createsamples stopped working

Tags: opencv

I just started learning opencv. I was trying to create training samples and it poped out saying createsamples has stopped working. Any help will be fully appreciated. Thanks!!

here's what i wrote and got:

```
c:\10X\newtest>C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_createsamples.exe -info positives.dat -bg negatives.dat -vec cropped.vec -num 2560 -w 48 -h 48


Info file name: positives.dat
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: cropped.vec
BG  file name: negatives.dat
Num: 2560
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Original image will be scaled to:
    Width: $backgroundWidth / 48
    Height: $backgroundHeight / 48
Create training samples from images collection...
Unable to open image: 0001_0186_0045_0059_0059.jpg
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -9 () in cvSetImageROI, file     C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 3000
```

Comment: Does `0001_0186_0045_0059_0059.jpg` exist?

Comment: 0001_0186_0045_0059_0059.jpg should be in the same directory as of opencv_createsamples.exe, or you should provide complete path for your image e.g C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Pictures\\0001_0186_0045_0059_0059.jpg

Comment: Thanks. it solved the problem, i should have included the path. Thanks a lot:)